# Amazon s3 error 500 when instantiating S3Client

Tags: php, amazon-aws, amazon-s3

The amazon php sdk is uploaded to site and the autoloader is included successfully. But I'm getting an error 500 with no further details. I believe I've isolated the issue to the instantiation of S3Client, as everything else works and if I comment out that it doens't give error 500. Code is as follows -

```
require $web_root.'/aws/aws-autoloader.php';

$keyname = "--keyname--";
$secret = "--secret key--";    

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

$s3 = new S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => $keyname,
        'secret' => $secret,
    ],
]);
```

As found in the example php code here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/usingHLmpuPHP.html

Why is returning error 500?

Comment: If you use intentionally wrong credentials, does the HTTP response status code change?

Comment: same results as with correct credentials

Answer (score 1):

Try to put

```
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
```

Just after the require statement and at the top before any other PHP code.